# Slurmd remains inactive/failed on start

Tags: cluster-computing, slurm

I currently have a cluster of 10 worker nodes managed by Slurm with 1 master node. I have previously successfully set up the cluster, after some teething problems, but managed to get it working. I put all my scripts and instructions on my GitHub repo (https://brettchapman.github.io/Nimbus_Cluster/). I recently needed to start over again to increase hard drive space, and now can't seem to install and configure it correctly no matter what I've tried.

Slurmctld and slurmdbd install and are configured correctly (both active and running with the systemctl status command), however slurmd remains in a failed/inactive state.

The following is my slurm.conf file:

```
# slurm.conf file generated by configurator.html.
# Put this file on all nodes of your cluster.
# See the slurm.conf man page for more information.
#
SlurmctldHost=node-0
#SlurmctldHost=
#
#DisableRootJobs=NO
#EnforcePartLimits=NO
#Epilog=
#EpilogSlurmctld=
#FirstJobId=1
#MaxJobId=999999
#GresTypes=
#GroupUpdateForce=0
#GroupUpdateTime=600
#JobFileAppend=0
#JobRequeue=1
#JobSubmitPlugins=1
#KillOnBadExit=0
#LaunchType=launch/slurm
#Licenses=foo*4,bar
#MailProg=/bin/mail
#MaxJobCount=5000
#MaxStepCount=40000
#MaxTasksPerNode=128
MpiDefault=none
#MpiParams=ports=#-#
#PluginDir=
#PlugStackConfig=
#PrivateData=jobs
ProctrackType=proctrack/cgroup
#Prolog=
#PrologFlags=
#PrologSlurmctld=
#PropagatePrioProcess=0
#PropagateResourceLimits=
#PropagateResourceLimitsExcept=
#RebootProgram=
ReturnToService=1
#SallocDefaultCommand=
SlurmctldPidFile=/var/run/slurmctld.pid
SlurmctldPort=6817
SlurmdPidFile=/var/run/slurmd.pid
SlurmdPort=6818
SlurmdSpoolDir=/var/spool/slurmd
SlurmUser=slurm
#SlurmdUser=root
#SrunEpilog=
#SrunProlog=
StateSaveLocation=/var/spool/slurm-llnl
SwitchType=switch/none
#TaskEpilog=
TaskPlugin=task/cgroup
#TaskPluginParam=
#TaskProlog=
#TopologyPlugin=topology/tree
#TmpFS=/tmp
#TrackWCKey=no
#TreeWidth=
#UnkillableStepProgram=
#UsePAM=0
#
#
# TIMERS
#BatchStartTimeout=10
#CompleteWait=0
#EpilogMsgTime=2000
#GetEnvTimeout=2
#HealthCheckInterval=0
#HealthCheckProgram=
InactiveLimit=0
KillWait=30
#MessageTimeout=10
#ResvOverRun=0
MinJobAge=300
#OverTimeLimit=0
SlurmctldTimeout=120
SlurmdTimeout=600
#UnkillableStepTimeout=60
#VSizeFactor=0
Waittime=0
#
#
# SCHEDULING
#DefMemPerCPU=0
#MaxMemPerCPU=0
#SchedulerTimeSlice=30
SchedulerType=sched/backfill
SelectType=select/cons_res
SelectTypeParameters=CR_Core
#
#
# JOB PRIORITY
#PriorityFlags=
#PriorityType=priority/basic
#PriorityDecayHalfLife=
#PriorityCalcPeriod=
#PriorityFavorSmall=
#PriorityMaxAge=
#PriorityUsageResetPeriod=
#PriorityWeightAge=
#PriorityWeightFairshare=
#PriorityWeightJobSize=
#PriorityWeightPartition=
#PriorityWeightQOS=
#
#
# LOGGING AND ACCOUNTING
#AccountingStorageEnforce=0
#AccountingStorageHost=
#AccountingStorageLoc=
#AccountingStoragePass=
#AccountingStoragePort=
AccountingStorageType=accounting_storage/filetxt
#AccountingStorageUser=
AccountingStoreJobComment=YES
ClusterName=cluster
#DebugFlags=
JobCompHost=localhost
JobCompLoc=slurm_acct_db
JobCompPass=password
#JobCompPort=
JobCompType=jobcomp/mysql
JobCompUser=slurm
#JobContainerType=job_container/none
JobAcctGatherFrequency=30
JobAcctGatherType=jobacct_gather/none
SlurmctldDebug=info
SlurmctldLogFile=/var/log/slurm-llnl/slurmctld.log
SlurmdDebug=info
SlurmdLogFile=/var/log/slurm-llnl/slurmd.log
#SlurmSchedLogFile=
#SlurmSchedLogLevel=
#
#
# POWER SAVE SUPPORT FOR IDLE NODES (optional)
#SuspendProgram=
#ResumeProgram=
#SuspendTimeout=
#ResumeTimeout=
#ResumeRate=
#SuspendExcNodes=
#SuspendExcParts=
#SuspendRate=
#SuspendTime=
#
#
# COMPUTE NODES
NodeName=node-[1-10] NodeAddr=node-[1-10] CPUs=16 RealMemory=64323 Sockets=1 CoresPerSocket=8 ThreadsPerCore=2 State=UNKNOWN
PartitionName=debug Nodes=node-[1-10] Default=YES MaxTime=INFINITE State=UP
```

And the following is my slurmdbd.conf file:

```
AuthType=auth/munge
AuthInfo=/run/munge/munge.socket.2
DbdHost=localhost
DebugLevel=info
StorageHost=localhost
StorageLoc=slurm_acct_db
StoragePass=password
StorageType=accounting_storage/mysql
StorageUser=slurm
LogFile=/var/log/slurm-llnl/slurmdbd.log
PidFile=/var/run/slurmdbd.pid
SlurmUser=slurm
```

Running pdsh -a sudo systemctl status slurmd on my compute nodes gives me the following error:

```
pdsh@node-0: node-5: ssh exited with exit code 3
node-6: ● slurmd.service - Slurm node daemon
node-6:      Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/slurmd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
node-6:      Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2020-08-11 03:52:58 UTC; 2min 45s ago
node-6:        Docs: man:slurmd(8)
node-6:     Process: 9068 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/slurmd $SLURMD_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
node-6:    Main PID: 8983
node-6: 
node-6: Aug 11 03:34:09 node-6 systemd[1]: Starting Slurm node daemon...
node-6: Aug 11 03:34:09 node-6 systemd[1]: slurmd.service: Supervising process 8983 which is not our child. We'll most likely not notice when it exits.
node-6: Aug 11 03:34:09 node-6 systemd[1]: Started Slurm node daemon.
node-6: Aug 11 03:52:58 node-6 systemd[1]: slurmd.service: Killing process 8983 (n/a) with signal SIGKILL.
node-6: Aug 11 03:52:58 node-6 systemd[1]: slurmd.service: Killing process 8983 (n/a) with signal SIGKILL.
node-6: Aug 11 03:52:58 node-6 systemd[1]: slurmd.service: Succeeded.
pdsh@node-0: node-6: ssh exited with exit code 3
```

I did not previously receive this type of error before when I had my cluster up and running, so I'm unsure of what I did or didn't do between now and last time I had it running. My guess is it's something to do with file/folder permissions, as I have found that can be quite critical when setting up. I may have missed documenting something I did previously. This is my second attempt at setting up a slurm managed cluster.

My entire workflow and scripts can be followed from my GitHub repo. If you need any other error outputs, please ask.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Brett

EDIT:

Looking in one of node-1 and running sudo slurmd -Dvvv I get this:

```
slurmd: debug:  Log file re-opened
slurmd: debug2: hwloc_topology_init
slurmd: debug2: hwloc_topology_load
slurmd: debug2: hwloc_topology_export_xml
slurmd: debug:  CPUs:16 Boards:1 Sockets:1 CoresPerSocket:8 ThreadsPerCore:2
slurmd: Message aggregation disabled
slurmd: debug:  Reading cgroup.conf file /etc/slurm-llnl/cgroup.conf
slurmd: debug2: hwloc_topology_init
slurmd: debug2: xcpuinfo_hwloc_topo_load: xml file (/var/spool/slurmd/hwloc_topo_whole.xml) found
slurmd: debug:  CPUs:16 Boards:1 Sockets:1 CoresPerSocket:8 ThreadsPerCore:2
slurmd: topology NONE plugin loaded
slurmd: route default plugin loaded
slurmd: CPU frequency setting not configured for this node
slurmd: debug:  Resource spec: No specialized cores configured by default on this node
slurmd: debug:  Resource spec: Reserved system memory limit not configured for this node
slurmd: debug:  Reading cgroup.conf file /etc/slurm-llnl/cgroup.conf
slurmd: debug:  task/cgroup: now constraining jobs allocated cores
slurmd: debug:  task/cgroup/memory: total:64323M allowed:100%(enforced), swap:0%(permissive), max:100%(64323M) max+swap:100%(128646M) min:30M kmem:100%(64323M permissive) min:30M swappiness:0(unset)
slurmd: debug:  task/cgroup: now constraining jobs allocated memory
slurmd: debug:  task/cgroup: unable to open /etc/slurm-llnl/cgroup_allowed_devices_file.conf: No such file or directory
slurmd: debug:  task/cgroup: now constraining jobs allocated devices
slurmd: debug:  task/cgroup: loaded
slurmd: debug:  Munge authentication plugin loaded
slurmd: debug:  spank: opening plugin stack /etc/slurm-llnl/plugstack.conf
slurmd: debug:  /etc/slurm-llnl/plugstack.conf: 1: include "/etc/slurm-llnl/plugstack.conf.d/*.conf"
slurmd: Munge credential signature plugin loaded
slurmd: slurmd version 19.05.5 started
slurmd: debug:  Job accounting gather NOT_INVOKED plugin loaded
slurmd: debug:  job_container none plugin loaded
slurmd: debug:  switch NONE plugin loaded
slurmd: error: Error binding slurm stream socket: Address already in use
slurmd: error: Unable to bind listen port (*:6818): Address already in use
```

Logging into a differnt node, node-10, I get this:

```
slurmd: debug:  Log file re-opened
slurmd: debug2: hwloc_topology_init
slurmd: debug2: hwloc_topology_load
slurmd: debug2: hwloc_topology_export_xml
slurmd: debug:  CPUs:16 Boards:1 Sockets:1 CoresPerSocket:8 ThreadsPerCore:2
slurmd: Message aggregation disabled
slurmd: debug:  Reading cgroup.conf file /etc/slurm-llnl/cgroup.conf
slurmd: debug2: hwloc_topology_init
slurmd: debug2: xcpuinfo_hwloc_topo_load: xml file (/var/spool/slurmd/hwloc_topo_whole.xml) found
slurmd: debug:  CPUs:16 Boards:1 Sockets:1 CoresPerSocket:8 ThreadsPerCore:2
slurmd: topology NONE plugin loaded
slurmd: route default plugin loaded
slurmd: CPU frequency setting not configured for this node
slurmd: debug:  Resource spec: No specialized cores configured by default on this node
slurmd: debug:  Resource spec: Reserved system memory limit not configured for this node
slurmd: debug:  Reading cgroup.conf file /etc/slurm-llnl/cgroup.conf
slurmd: debug:  task/cgroup: now constraining jobs allocated cores
slurmd: debug:  task/cgroup/memory: total:64323M allowed:100%(enforced), swap:0%(permissive), max:100%(64323M) max+swap:100%(128646M) min:30M kmem:100%(64323M permissive) min:30M swappiness:0(unset)
slurmd: debug:  task/cgroup: now constraining jobs allocated memory
slurmd: debug:  task/cgroup: unable to open /etc/slurm-llnl/cgroup_allowed_devices_file.conf: No such file or directory
slurmd: debug:  task/cgroup: now constraining jobs allocated devices
slurmd: debug:  task/cgroup: loaded
slurmd: debug:  Munge authentication plugin loaded
slurmd: debug:  spank: opening plugin stack /etc/slurm-llnl/plugstack.conf
slurmd: debug:  /etc/slurm-llnl/plugstack.conf: 1: include "/etc/slurm-llnl/plugstack.conf.d/*.conf"
slurmd: Munge credential signature plugin loaded
slurmd: slurmd version 19.05.5 started
slurmd: debug:  Job accounting gather NOT_INVOKED plugin loaded
slurmd: debug:  job_container none plugin loaded
slurmd: debug:  switch NONE plugin loaded
slurmd: slurmd started on Tue, 11 Aug 2020 06:56:10 +0000
slurmd: CPUs=16 Boards=1 Sockets=1 Cores=8 Threads=2 Memory=64323 TmpDisk=297553 Uptime=756 CPUSpecList=(null) FeaturesAvail=(null) FeaturesActive=(null)
slurmd: debug:  AcctGatherEnergy NONE plugin loaded
slurmd: debug:  AcctGatherProfile NONE plugin loaded
slurmd: debug:  AcctGatherInterconnect NONE plugin loaded
slurmd: debug:  AcctGatherFilesystem NONE plugin loaded
slurmd: debug2: No acct_gather.conf file (/etc/slurm-llnl/acct_gather.conf)
slurmd: debug:  _handle_node_reg_resp: slurmctld sent back 8 TRES.
```

Another node, node-5, I get this, the same as node-1:

```
slurmd: debug:  Log file re-opened
slurmd: debug2: hwloc_topology_init
slurmd: debug2: hwloc_topology_load
slurmd: debug2: hwloc_topology_export_xml
slurmd: debug:  CPUs:16 Boards:1 Sockets:1 CoresPerSocket:8 ThreadsPerCore:2
slurmd: Message aggregation disabled
slurmd: debug:  Reading cgroup.conf file /etc/slurm-llnl/cgroup.conf
slurmd: debug2: hwloc_topology_init
slurmd: debug2: xcpuinfo_hwloc_topo_load: xml file (/var/spool/slurmd/hwloc_topo_whole.xml) found
slurmd: debug:  CPUs:16 Boards:1 Sockets:1 CoresPerSocket:8 ThreadsPerCore:2
slurmd: topology NONE plugin loaded
slurmd: route default plugin loaded
slurmd: CPU frequency setting not configured for this node
slurmd: debug:  Resource spec: No specialized cores configured by default on this node
slurmd: debug:  Resource spec: Reserved system memory limit not configured for this node
slurmd: debug:  Reading cgroup.conf file /etc/slurm-llnl/cgroup.conf
slurmd: debug:  task/cgroup: now constraining jobs allocated cores
slurmd: debug:  task/cgroup/memory: total:64323M allowed:100%(enforced), swap:0%(permissive), max:100%(64323M) max+swap:100%(128646M) min:30M kmem:100%(64323M permissive) min:30M swappiness:0(unset)
slurmd: debug:  task/cgroup: now constraining jobs allocated memory
slurmd: debug:  task/cgroup: unable to open /etc/slurm-llnl/cgroup_allowed_devices_file.conf: No such file or directory
slurmd: debug:  task/cgroup: now constraining jobs allocated devices
slurmd: debug:  task/cgroup: loaded
slurmd: debug:  Munge authentication plugin loaded
slurmd: debug:  spank: opening plugin stack /etc/slurm-llnl/plugstack.conf
slurmd: debug:  /etc/slurm-llnl/plugstack.conf: 1: include "/etc/slurm-llnl/plugstack.conf.d/*.conf"
slurmd: Munge credential signature plugin loaded
slurmd: slurmd version 19.05.5 started
slurmd: debug:  Job accounting gather NOT_INVOKED plugin loaded
slurmd: debug:  job_container none plugin loaded
slurmd: debug:  switch NONE plugin loaded
slurmd: error: Error binding slurm stream socket: Address already in use
slurmd: error: Unable to bind listen port (*:6818): Address already in use
```

node-10 was down previously, and I struggled to bring it back up, so the error may be unrelated to the overall problem.

Edit2: After killing stuck slurmd processes across all nodes, slurmd still fails on start:

```
slurmd.service - Slurm node daemon
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/slurmd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: timeout) since Tue 2020-08-11 07:10:42 UTC; 3min 58s ago
       Docs: man:slurmd(8)

Aug 11 07:09:11 node-1 systemd[1]: Starting Slurm node daemon...
Aug 11 07:09:11 node-1 systemd[1]: slurmd.service: Can't open PID file /run/slurmd.pid (yet?) after start: Operation not permitted
Aug 11 07:10:42 node-1 systemd[1]: slurmd.service: start operation timed out. Terminating.
Aug 11 07:10:42 node-1 systemd[1]: slurmd.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
Aug 11 07:10:42 node-1 systemd[1]: Failed to start Slurm node daemon.
```

The sudo slurmd -Dvvv output on node1:

```
slurmd: debug:  Log file re-opened
slurmd: debug2: hwloc_topology_init
slurmd: debug2: hwloc_topology_load
slurmd: debug2: hwloc_topology_export_xml
slurmd: debug:  CPUs:16 Boards:1 Sockets:1 CoresPerSocket:8 ThreadsPerCore:2
slurmd: Message aggregation disabled
slurmd: debug:  Reading cgroup.conf file /etc/slurm-llnl/cgroup.conf
slurmd: debug2: hwloc_topology_init
slurmd: debug2: xcpuinfo_hwloc_topo_load: xml file (/var/spool/slurmd/hwloc_topo_whole.xml) found
slurmd: debug:  CPUs:16 Boards:1 Sockets:1 CoresPerSocket:8 ThreadsPerCore:2
slurmd: topology NONE plugin loaded
slurmd: route default plugin loaded
slurmd: CPU frequency setting not configured for this node
slurmd: debug:  Resource spec: No specialized cores configured by default on this node
slurmd: debug:  Resource spec: Reserved system memory limit not configured for this node
slurmd: debug:  Reading cgroup.conf file /etc/slurm-llnl/cgroup.conf
slurmd: debug:  task/cgroup: now constraining jobs allocated cores
slurmd: debug:  task/cgroup/memory: total:64323M allowed:100%(enforced), swap:0%(permissive), max:100%(64323M) max+swap:100%(128646M) min:30M kmem:100%(64323M permissive) min:30M swappiness:0(unset)
slurmd: debug:  task/cgroup: now constraining jobs allocated memory
slurmd: debug:  task/cgroup: unable to open /etc/slurm-llnl/cgroup_allowed_devices_file.conf: No such file or directory
slurmd: debug:  task/cgroup: now constraining jobs allocated devices
slurmd: debug:  task/cgroup: loaded
slurmd: debug:  Munge authentication plugin loaded
slurmd: debug:  spank: opening plugin stack /etc/slurm-llnl/plugstack.conf
slurmd: debug:  /etc/slurm-llnl/plugstack.conf: 1: include "/etc/slurm-llnl/plugstack.conf.d/*.conf"
slurmd: Munge credential signature plugin loaded
slurmd: slurmd version 19.05.5 started
slurmd: debug:  Job accounting gather NOT_INVOKED plugin loaded
slurmd: debug:  job_container none plugin loaded
slurmd: debug:  switch NONE plugin loaded
slurmd: slurmd started on Tue, 11 Aug 2020 07:14:08 +0000
slurmd: CPUs=16 Boards=1 Sockets=1 Cores=8 Threads=2 Memory=64323 TmpDisk=297553 Uptime=15897 CPUSpecList=(null) FeaturesAvail=(null) FeaturesActive=(null)
slurmd: debug:  AcctGatherEnergy NONE plugin loaded
slurmd: debug:  AcctGatherProfile NONE plugin loaded
slurmd: debug:  AcctGatherInterconnect NONE plugin loaded
slurmd: debug:  AcctGatherFilesystem NONE plugin loaded
slurmd: debug2: No acct_gather.conf file (/etc/slurm-llnl/acct_gather.conf)
slurmd: debug:  _handle_node_reg_resp: slurmctld sent back 8 TRES.
```

Edit3: I get these debug messages from the slurmd.log file, which seem to indicate the PID can't be retrieved and certain files/folders are not accessible:

```
[2020-08-11T07:38:27.973] slurmd version 19.05.5 started
[2020-08-11T07:38:27.973] debug:  Job accounting gather NOT_INVOKED plugin loaded
[2020-08-11T07:38:27.973] debug:  job_container none plugin loaded
[2020-08-11T07:38:27.973] debug:  switch NONE plugin loaded
[2020-08-11T07:38:27.973] slurmd started on Tue, 11 Aug 2020 07:38:27 +0000
[2020-08-11T07:38:27.973] CPUs=16 Boards=1 Sockets=1 Cores=8 Threads=2 Memory=64323 TmpDisk=297553 Uptime=17357 CPUSpecList=(null) FeaturesAvail=(null) FeaturesActive=(null)
[2020-08-11T07:38:27.973] debug:  AcctGatherEnergy NONE plugin loaded
[2020-08-11T07:38:27.973] debug:  AcctGatherProfile NONE plugin loaded
[2020-08-11T07:38:27.974] debug:  AcctGatherInterconnect NONE plugin loaded
[2020-08-11T07:38:27.974] debug:  AcctGatherFilesystem NONE plugin loaded
[2020-08-11T07:38:27.974] debug2: No acct_gather.conf file (/etc/slurm-llnl/acct_gather.conf)
[2020-08-11T07:38:27.975] debug:  _handle_node_reg_resp: slurmctld sent back 8 TRES.
[2020-08-11T07:38:33.496] got shutdown request
[2020-08-11T07:38:33.496] all threads complete
[2020-08-11T07:38:33.496] debug2: _file_read_uint32s: unable to open '(null)/tasks' for reading : No such file or directory
[2020-08-11T07:38:33.496] debug2: xcgroup_get_pids: unable to get pids of '(null)'
[2020-08-11T07:38:33.496] debug2: _file_read_uint32s: unable to open '(null)/tasks' for reading : No such file or directory
[2020-08-11T07:38:33.496] debug2: xcgroup_get_pids: unable to get pids of '(null)'
[2020-08-11T07:38:33.497] debug2: _file_read_uint32s: unable to open '(null)/tasks' for reading : No such file or directory
[2020-08-11T07:38:33.497] debug2: xcgroup_get_pids: unable to get pids of '(null)'
[2020-08-11T07:38:33.497] Consumable Resources (CR) Node Selection plugin shutting down ...
[2020-08-11T07:38:33.497] Munge credential signature plugin unloaded
[2020-08-11T07:38:33.497] Slurmd shutdown completing
```

Edit4: slurmd is active, but only after running sudo service slurmd restart. Running stop and then start does not activate slurmd.

```
● slurmd.service - Slurm node daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/slurmd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-08-11 08:17:46 UTC; 1min 37s ago
       Docs: man:slurmd(8)
    Process: 28281 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/slurmd $SLURMD_OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 28474
      Tasks: 0
     Memory: 1.1M
     CGroup: /system.slice/slurmd.service

Aug 11 08:17:46 node-1 systemd[1]: Starting Slurm node daemon...
Aug 11 08:17:46 node-1 systemd[1]: slurmd.service: Can't open PID file /run/slurmd.pid (yet?) after start: Operation not permitted
Aug 11 08:17:46 node-1 systemd[1]: Started Slurm node daemon.
Aug 11 08:18:41 node-1 systemd[1]: slurmd.service: Supervising process 28474 which is not our child. We'll most likely not notice when it exits.
```

Edit5: another issue which may be related, is that sacct can only be run with sudo, and it complains about permissions to the log file. I tried changing the permissions to /var/log but it caused problems since its a system folder:

```
ubuntu@node-0:/data/pangenome_cactus$ sacct
       JobID    JobName  Partition    Account  AllocCPUS      State ExitCode 
------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -------- 
/var/log/slurm_jobacct.log: Permission denied
ubuntu@node-0:/data/pangenome_cactus$ sudo sacct
       JobID    JobName  Partition    Account  AllocCPUS      State ExitCode 
------------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -------- 
2            cactus_pa+      debug     (null)          0     FAILED    127:0 
3            cactus_pa+      debug     (null)          0    RUNNING      0:0 
3.0          singulari+                (null)          0    RUNNING      0:0
```

Comment: Try starting the `slurmd` daemon interactively in debug mode: `slurmd -Dvvv` on a compute node ; the output should help figuring out what is happening.

Comment: Thanks. I had usually ran interatively from pdsh. Logging in and running I found this error: error: Error binding slurm stream socket: Address already in use
error: Unable to bind listen port (*:6818): Address already in use. Which is weird. 6818 is specified in the slurm.conf file and was the same last time I set up slurm. Not sure why it's complaining now.

Comment: You probably have `slurmd` processes still running but not responding. Try `ps aux |grep slurm` and kill any process found.

Comment: Thanks. That removed the port error after I killed all the processes running slurmd. After I start all the slurm services again, I still get the failed slurmd error (see edit2 above).

Comment: there is no error in there. Does the `scontrol ping` command run on a compute node respond properly? might there be firewalls between the compute nodes and the controller?

Comment: scontrol ping running on my compute nodes comes back with Slurmctld(primary) at node-0 is UP. The instance configuration of all nodes is the same as it was previously when slurmd was running. I can ssh into each node from the master node with no problems (I'm using ForwardAgent to pass on my SSH credentials). I'm not aware of any firewalls between nodes within the cluster. There shouldn't be as it's the network setup I had previously, which was working fine.

Comment: I've gotten all nodes to an idle state, and after starting all services again, slurmd goes to an inactive state. However, when I run sudo service slurmd restart, I find the nodes go to an active state, but only when I run the restart command, not stop and then start. I found this to be the case early on in my investigation to my problem. I didn't need to run restart previously when I configured my cluster. Yesterday I ran a job after slurmd was active again, but the following day they were inactive while the job was still running, so I doubt they'll continue to remain active for long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `slurmd` daemon says `got shutdown request`, so it was terminated by `systemd` probably because of `Can't open PID file /run/slurmd.pid (yet?) after start`. `systemd` is configured to consider that `slurmd` starts successfully if the PID file `/run/slurmd.pid` exists. But the Slurm configuration states `SlurmdPidFile=/var/run/slurmd.pid`. Try changing it to `SlurmdPidFile=/run/slurmd.pid`.

Comment: I've also tried that previously. /var/run symlinks to /run/. I just tried it again and edited the slurm.conf file and I still get the same result with slurmd inactive on start, but is active on restart. See the status report after restart in edit4.

Comment: I'm going to try and run a job, and see how it goes over night. If the problem still persists, I'm tempted to destroy the cluster and start again, and see if the problem disappears. It isn't entirely clear what is causing the issue. It's also entirely possible there may be network issues, as I'm running the instances from a cluster hosted by a local supercomputing facility here. If it happens again, I'll contact the sys admin there to look into network connectivity between the instances.

Comment: One other thing may be the permissions. I've looked at the pid files for slurmctld and slurmdbd and all are slurm:root, however on the compute nodes slurmd.pid is root:root. I've just run chown slurm:root on the slurmd.pid files to see if that helps.

Comment: this is normal: `slurmctld` should run as user `slurm` but `slurmd` should run as user `root`

Comment: Thanks. I changed the permissions back. I decided to resinstall from the beginning, and go through each line of code in my slurm install setup scripts. I ended up with the exact same problem where my slurmd processes on each node were not active, unless I run restart, instead of stop and then start. This isn't the same behavior I had the first time round I set up slurm a few months ago. For now I'll leave it. slurmd remained active over night, I'll just run restart if they go inactive/failed. Thanks for your help. I'll post an update if the problem persists or another problem arises.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to add some of my opinions to this question since I think my solution works. "Slurmd" does not seem to care if the PidFile path exist or not. However, it will return error-code when running as daemon if it fails to write into the given path. Linux service catches the error-code and thinks daemon failed to start but in reality "slurmd" already started. This is why you get "Address already in use" error when trying to start it again. So, the solution to this is to ensure the PidFile path does exist when the machine boots up.

**#solution #1**

Don't create files under /var/run. Use some other directory that is not for "root". If you want to use /var/run, go to solution #2.

**#solution #2**

/var/run is a temporary directory created in the memory. It will not persist between reboot. Another problem is "/var/run" is for "root" user not "slurm". This is why "slurmd" has no right to write into it. So I would recommend create /var/run/slurm and put everything in there.

To solve this problem, we can reference "Munge". If you do "ls -l /var/run/" you will notice "/var/run/munge" has user "munge" and group "munge". Also, munge is able to create "/var/run/munge" directory upon start.

To create the directory under "/var/run" upon start, simply create a file under /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/slurm.conf (again this is how munge did it. You can reference /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/munge.conf).

```
d /var/run/slurm 0755 slurm slurm -
d /var/log/slurm 0755 slurm slurm -
d /var/spool/slurm 0755 slurm slurm -
```

Then, make sure your slurm.conf, slurmd.service, slurmctld.service has PidFile point to the same location as above.

This is it. It should do the trick. I also run into another weird problem where the service will fail upon start and I had to add "Restart=on-failure" and "RestartSec=5" to my services so that it will eventually succeed (about 10~20s). This is not neat but does work.